# f.date_select: display month and year together in one single option menu?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

Instead of separate option menus (one for `year` and one for `month`), how could I merge `year` and `month` into visually one single menu for a `date` attribute?

Each option would be a year/month pair, i.e.

`2014 January`
`2014 February`

Currently I have this code: `f.date_select :begin_date, discard_day: true` (to visually exclude the days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like the following small jQueryUI code, which does exactly what you describe: http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/

Comment: I had initially a "traditional" scroll menu in mind, but at second thought that could potentially result in quite a lot of scrolling.. So this is a real good alternative, thanks!